# Do not display anything until everything is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I am using the JS Facebook Graph API and want to load a friends list with profile pictures and this takes a few seconds if there are a lot of friends. I want to display a loading div, and once everything is loaded I want to hide the loading div and show the friendliest. I am using JQuery's $(window).load function, but it does not seem to work, the loading div does not show, but still shows content rendering. I think this may be because I'm making the Facebook request in the middle of my page, so the browser might think at the beginning everything is loaded, but have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: Since you are making the facebook request after you start loading the page, I assume you are making an AJAX request. You should hide the loading div at the callback of that AJAX request

Comment: please post some code...

Answer (score 1):

Put your whole page in a `<div style="display:none;">` or simply set the `<body style="display:none;">` then change it to :block (using jQuery.show() will work) once you have received the data you are requesting from Facebook.

Comment: `code`                                                            FB.api('/me/friends', function(response) {                        var result_holder = document.getElementById('result_friends');
   
var results = '';

for (var i = 0; i < friend_data.length; i++) {
      
results += '<div>stuff here from facebook</div>';
}// and display them at our holder element
result_holder.innerHTML = '<h2>Result list of your friends:</h2>' + results; }`code`                                                                So how would I know when it is rendered?

Comment: I'm really not sure how to answer that question. (document).ready will normally suffice in the case of a simple http request. With an AJAX request, I normally rely on http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/

Comment: I am not waiting for ajax to finish though, I am waiting for html to finish after the ajax call, so essentially I am using JQuery's innerhtml function, so how would I wait for that to display?

Comment: Unless you are loading a ton of data, it should render almost immediately. The only exception would be images. In that case, you might try looping through your image collection and checking the complete property. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_complete.asp